# ng-repeat multiple radiobutton groups with "checked" property -- only last group gets checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

See [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/camawemo/3/edit)

For each item in an array, I'm trying to create a list of 6 radio buttons, where the fourth item is initially the checked value in all of them.  When this renders, however, only the fourth item of the last group of radio buttons is checked.  The `name="checkpoint{{$index}}"` is working, as the groups are individually selectable, just the initial setting of the values is not.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="checkpoint in checkpoints">
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="checkpoint{{$index}}" />
        <input type="radio" name="checkpoint{{$index}}" />
        <input type="radio" name="checkpoint{{$index}}" />
        <input type="radio" name="checkpoint{{$index}}" checked /> <!-- This checked property is only working on the last set of radio buttons -->
        <input type="radio" name="checkpoint{{$index}}" />
        <input type="radio" name="checkpoint{{$index}}" />
        checkpoint{{$index}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the javascript for that:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.checkpoints = [
    {
      name: "one"
    },
    {
      name: "two"
    },
    {
      name: "three"
    },
    {
      name: "four"
    }
  ];
});
```

Comment: It sounds like a simple question but I can't figure out what you're asking. Could you isolate the answerable question part>

Comment: So, looking at the jsBin, you see the four sets of 6 radio buttons.  On the last set, the fourth radio button is selected.  Why isn't the fourth radio button selected in all four sets of radio buttons?

Comment: Added html comments to the line in the html that is causing the specific problem @itcouldevenbeaboat

Comment: I've had a look and everything seems to be working well. This might be a bug with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
ng-checked="true"
```

Instead of the native `checked`.

Edit:
Documentation for ngChecked for reference.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked